# programa que peça o nome e a data (ano, mês e dia) de nascimento de uma pessoa em Python

Tags: python

Olá, 
estou com dificuldades no seguinte código em *Python*:.

A ideia é criar um programa  que peça o nome e a data (ano, mês e dia) de
nascimento de uma pessoa.

O programa deverá também pedir a data atual (ano, mês e dia).

Com base nestas datas, deverá determinar a idade da pessoa.

Exempo de resultado:

Como se chama? Joaquim

Nasceu em que ano? 2001

Nasceu em que mes? 2

Nasceu em que dia? 23

Em que ano estamos? 2018

Em que mes estamos? 4

Em que dia estamos? 9

O Joaquim tem 16 anos

O problema está em se uma pessoa faz anos em Abril dia 5 de 1974 e a data atual é Janeiro dia 2 de 2018, essa pessoa devia ter 43 anos!

E é aqui que me está a dar sempre 44 anos! Não sei se me fiz entender!??!

[Aqui está o meu codigo](https://repl.it/@jpfernandes/Exercicio2Idade-1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Certo, você pode criar dois objetos de data(dataNasc e dataAtual) e subtrair para obter o timedelta(diferença entre ambos) e após isso considerar a média de dias de um ano, ficando mais ou menos assim.

```
import datetime

#Entrada de valores
print('='*18)
print('Exercício 2: idade')
print('='*18)
nome = input ("Como se chama? ")
ano = eval (input ("Nasceu em que ano? "))
mes = eval (input ("Nasceu em que mês? "))
dia = eval (input ("Nasceu em que dia? "))
ano_atual = eval (input ("Ano atual? "))
mes_atual = eval (input ("Mês atual? "))
dia_atual = eval (input ("Dia atual? "))
dataNasc = datetime.date(ano, mes, dia)
dataAtual = datetime.date(ano_atual, mes_atual, dia_atual)

#diferença retorna em timedelta
diferenca = (dataAtual - dataNasc)
#Cálculos e Resultados
rslt = (diferenca.days / 365.25)
#ano_atual-ano

if (dia == dia_atual and mes == mes_atual):
    print ("O %s tem %d anos!" %(nome, rslt))
else:
    ((dia > dia_atual and mes == mes_atual) or mes < mes_atual)
    print ("O %s tem %d anos!" %(nome, rslt))
```

Para mais dúvidas a respeito de comparações com datas e manipulações [acesso aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

Comment: O problema está em se uma pessoa faz anos em Abril dia 5 de 1974 e a data atual é Janeiro dia 2 de 2018, essa pessoa devia ter 43 anos!

E é aqui que me está a dar sempre 44 anos! Não sei se me fiz entender!??!

Comment: editei a resposta, verifique se dessa forma ficou claro.

Comment: estou com erro na compilação do codigo:
==================
Exercício 2: idade
==================
Como se chama?  joao
Nasceu em que ano?  1974
Nasceu em que mês?  4
Nasceu em que dia?  1
Ano atual?  2018
Mês atual?  2
Dia atual?  1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 12, in <module>
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined

Comment: Você colocou o import datetime no inicio? o código postado aqui está rodando normalmente aqui para mim

Comment: Já dá!! Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -3):

from datetime import date
import datetime

dia = int(input('Dia: '))
mes = int(input('Mes: '))
ano = int(input('Ano: '))

data = datetime.date(ano, mes, dia)
diferenca = (data.today() - data)
rslt = (diferenca / 365.25)

print('Você nasceu {}/{}/{} e tem {} anos'.format(data.day, data.month, data.year, rslt.days))